# What is the name of my Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use Vue for a little project.
I started with only client code. So when I did

```
const mv = new Vue({...});
```

I was able to access to the component from outside with a `mv`.
Now I'm using Vue.cli, so I define my component inside a mv.vue and then I have

```
export default {
    data () {}
    }
```

Here, how can I get the nme of my component?

Thanks for any reply or hint :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? Not sure what you mean by "name of my component".

Comment: Yes. For example I used to modify the data by calling mv.data.myVar = 'foo'. Now I can't manage to access the data from outside the component...

Comment: did you use the Vue CLI to create a new project and now you're wondering how to add a component to the application's scope? Do you have a main.js file?

Comment: Yes I used Vue CLI to create a new project and I added all my components. There are all displaying. It's just one of them that is updating itself throw an AJAX call and the display is not refresh when the AJAX is done

Comment: And you just need a reference to the instance of the problematic Vue component?

Comment: Well I was trying to update the component from the result of the AJAX call, so outside the component. So I was wondering if it was the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144569/discussion-between-thanksd-and-fred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the name of the component , you can do this

```
this.$vnode.tag
```

If you want the parent component's name from its child do this

```
this.$parent.$vnode.tag
```

Comment: Perfect I get the component name. As @dan-gamble told me, I will not be able to access it throw the browser console. But thanks. I think it's the question answer ^^

Comment: Reminder that inside the `setup()` function of the composition API (vue3) one would use `getCurrentInstance()` to get access to `this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the very good @vamsi-krishna answer, and update it, I've discovered that Vue now often puts a prefix on the `$vnode.tag` along the lines of `vue-component-3-YourComponentName`.

You can fix this by using the following code. And perhaps, just in case of a missing tag, fall back to the ID of the root element in the component.

Occasionally, Vue doesn't pass back a component at all in its `errorHandler` and `warnHandler` global events. So I've handled that scenario first.

```
if (!vm){
    return '[unknown]'
}

if (vm.$vnode.tag) {
    const res = vm.$vnode.tag
    return res.replace(/vue-component-\d+-/i, '')
}

if (vm.$el.id) {
    return vm.$el.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name your component like so:

```
export default {
  name: 'mv',

  data () {
    return {}
  }
}
```

But to access it you'd need to use the name that you import it with. For example:

```
import theVariableIWantItToBe from './mv.vue'

console.log(theVariableIWantItToBe)
```

Comment: not 100% sure that this is what he means. Either way, the name should be a string. In your example, it's an undefined variable `mv`.

Comment: Yes @thanksdand and Dan, I get undefined variable. And either putting it as a String, I cannot access it throw the browser console.

Comment: @Fred you won't be able to access it through the browser console. The `vue-cli` requires it to go through `webpack` or `browserify` as they can understand `.vue` extensions. By default browsers can't.

Comment: OK I cannot access it throws the console...
But if I try with Dan method inside the component script I get undefined too :(

Comment: Maybe it's just not the good technic to accomplish what I want. I just have a data member that is not reactive and I don't understand why. So I was trying to do like I did, using the component name...